# Where to put helper class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

In my app i would like to add a helper class called `Prototyp`:

```
class Prototyp
    def initialize
        ......
        @fields = JSON.parse('{' + arr.join(',') + '}')
    end

    def correct(word)
        @fields.each do |key, array|
            word.gsub! "\\" + key , [array.hex].pack("U")
        end
        return word
    end
end
```

I first added it to the folder `lib` to `lib\Prototyp.rb`

Then i tried to call it within a model class:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.create(file)
        pro = Prototyp.new
        ...
```

But somehow i got this error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Person::Prototyp
C:/Sites/blazing/app/models/person.rb:3:in `create'
```

What do i wrong? And how can i fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class is named Prototype (with a trailing e) but the call and file are named "Prototyp".

Also check your configuration in application.rb, it should contains a line like:

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

This tells Rails to load the files that are under the lib folder.

Comment: Sorry but i changed the name of my class for this question and made this mistake! But the problem is the same

Comment: Sorry but this seems not to work!